# Efficient way to find the average of the rank of added scores to a list. Possibly a more efficient way of sorting or a math way?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, math

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to find the average of the ranks of a bunch of scores added to a list.

For example if the input is:
5
100
200
150
170
50

Then the program should output 2.2

There are 5 scores to be added

When 100 is entered it is ranked 1

When 200 is entered it is ranked 1

When 150 is entered it is ranked 2

When 170 is entered it is ranked 2

when 50 is entered it is ranked 5

Then (1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 5) = 2.2

Right now I have a solution that works perfectly but It is not fast enough for large test cases.

```
games = input()
lst = []
acc = 0.0
counter = 0.0
for i in range(0, games):
    number = input()
    lst.append(number)
    lstt = sorted(lst)
    lsttt = lstt[::-1]
    acc += (lsttt.index(number) + 1)
print acc / games
```

Right now i am using the default python sort function, and I'm thinking using a different kind of sort could make it faster. Is that the issue or is there a better math way to do it?

Comment: 1) Why do you need to sort the list and 2) what's the purpose of the 5 in the beginning of the list?

Comment: The 5 is the number of scores to be added. And I need to sort them to find where they are ranked within all the scores added so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) package here, as it provides `O(log N)` insertion. So, with that package overall complexity is going to be `O(NlogN)`. Read its implementation details here: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

def solve_sorted_list(numbers):
    lst = SortedList()
    acc = 0.0
    for n in numbers:
        pos = lst.bisect(n)
        lst.add(n)
        acc += len(lst) - pos
    return acc / len(numbers)

print solve_sorted_list([100, 200, 150, 170, 50])
#2.2
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
>>> lst = range(10**5, -1, -1)
>>> %timeit solve_bisect(lst)   #Using NPE's solution
1 loops, best of 3: 1.87 s per loop
>>> %timeit solve_sorted_list(lst)
1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop
>>> lst = range(10**6, -1, -1)
>>> %timeit solve_sorted_list(lst)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.31 s per loop
>>> %timeit solve_bisect(lst)
1 loops, best of 3: 3min 52s per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to find the insertion point in `O(log(n))` time:

```
import bisect

games = input()
lst = []
acc = 0.0
counter = 0.0
for i in range(games):
    number = input()
    pos = bisect.bisect(lst, number)
    lst.insert(pos, number)  # O(log(n)) for the search, but O(n) for the insertion
    acc += len(lst) - pos
print acc / games
```

It's an improvement over your algorithm in that it's `O(n^2)` rather than `O((n^2)*log(n))`. If that's still too slow, you might want to consider using a tree.

Comment: Still not fast enough. How would I make a tree?